# Hidden Content and Jquery 2 Clicks to Fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I know there are a few questions related, but I wanted to ask the question more clearly. I took the time to duplicate my issue on jsfiddle (link at bottom).

I have a jquery event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ui.contact.selection.dropdown').on("click", function () {
         $(this).dropdown()
         ;
    })

});
```

The dropdown menu is located inside of a modal, which isn't actually present until THAT div is clicked, with

```
    $('.item.contact').on("click", function () {
        $('.ui.modal')
          .modal('show')
          ;
    })
```

The problem is that when I load the modal, and then click the dropdown menu, the menu takes two clicks before it fires. I am guessing this is because the dropdown isn't available on page load.  The first click loads it, the second click fires it?  I'm not sure but would appreciate assistance!

Please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8r0fzfg/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `show` option when you create the dropdown:

```
$(this).dropdown('show', true)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8r0fzfg/8/

Comment: @Peege151 After looking at a little, I think it is cleaner to call `dropdown()` when you create the modal.  This initializes the dropdown.  The clicking is then handled by the module, not by you.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8r0fzfg/10/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below and it works!

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.ui.contact.selection.dropdown').dropdown();    

    //CONTACT MODAL
    $('.item.contact').on("click", function () {
        $('.ui.modal').modal('show');       
    });    
});
```

I believe the "dropdown" should be fired on pre-loading.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage) for semantic, it seems that the first .dropdown will create the object, and the second will cause the toggle to fire (by default). If you want to make it a toggle operation, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    ...

    $('.ui.contact.selection.dropdown').dropdown();
    $('.ui.contact.selection.dropdown').on("click", function () {
        $(this).behavour("toggle");
    });
});
```

This event will handle not only open, but also close.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8r0fzfg/7/)